# My ViewModel changes are not reflected in my UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two bound textboxes in my View.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding BookingWizard.CustomerView.Email,Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding BookingWizard.CustomerView.ContactNo,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I can populate these fields when another textbox has lost its focus. the code behind for that bit is:

```
private void txtFirstName_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LookUpEmailAndContactNo();
}

private void LookUpEmailAndContactNo()
{
    var vm = this.DataContext as ApplicationViewModel;
    var customer = vm.BookingWizard.LookUpEmailAndContactNo();

    //etc        
    vm.BookingWizard.CustomerView.Email = customer.Email;

}

public Customer LookUpEmailAndContactNo()
{
    var res= InformedWorkerBusinessService.Customer.GetEmailAndContactNo(CustomerView.FName, CustomerView.SName);
    if (res!=null)
    {
        CustomerView.Email = res.Email;
        CustomerView.ContactNo = res.ContactNo;
    }
    return CustomerView;
}
```

This is the screenshot of my data context when i set a break-point in the **LookUpEmailAndContactNo** event:

[image]

As you can see the data context does have these values but I cannot see what is wrong with my UI binding?

**ADDITIONAL**:

I set my view model at the App entry point:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        ApplicationView app = new ApplicationView();
        ApplicationViewModel context = new ApplicationViewModel();
        context.ActiveRecord = new ActiveRecord();
        context.CustomerSearch = new CustomerSearch();
        context.BookingWizard = new BookingWizard();
        context.BookingWizard.CustomerView = new InformedWorkerModel.Customer();
        context.BookingWizard.JobView = new InformedWorkerModel.Job();
        app.DataContext = context;
        app.Show();
    }
}
```

This is inside my BookingWizard class:

```
public class BookingWizard : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    Customer _Customer; 

    public bool IsExistingCustomer { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> FNames
    {
        get
        {
            if (CustomerView.SName == null)
            {
                CustomerView.SName = string.Empty;
            }
            return InformedWorkerBusinessService.Customer.GetFirstNames(CustomerView.SName);
        }
    }

    public Customer LookUpEmailAndContactNo()
    {
        var res= InformedWorkerBusinessService.Customer.GetEmailAndContactNo(CustomerView.FName, CustomerView.SName);
        if (res!=null)
        {
            CustomerView.Email = res.Email;
            CustomerView.ContactNo = res.ContactNo;
        }
        return CustomerView;
    }

    public Customer CustomerView
    {
        get { return _Customer; }
        set
        {
            _Customer = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CustomerView");
        }
    }
}
```

and in my Customer Class:

```
[Table("Customer")]
public  class Customer
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }   

    public string SName { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }     
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get ; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just a small tip to find errors in Bindings: Look at the "output" window (debug -> windows -> output). It shows binding errors.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson are `BookingWizard`, `CustomerView` and `Email` **public properties**?

Comment: @FlatEric thanks for tip will do that now :)

Comment: @dkozl sorry for the delay. I will edit question to show you - thanks

Comment: Your view models look fine so far. But error suugests it cannot find `BookingWizard` in `ApplicationView`. Which means it's looking in wrong class

Comment: @dkozl Hi again.  not sure what you mean? :)

Comment: I don't know where but it seems you're replacing `DataContext` with `ApplicationView` - _path error: `BookingWizard` property not found on `ApplicationView`_ (not `ApplicationViewModel`)

Comment: @dkozl ApplicationView is a Window and I set the DataContext to that window. It is done in 'protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)'?

Comment: @dkozl I see what you are saying - going by that error. Had tried a solution and it gave that output.  i have now rescinded that 'solution' and that output no longer occurs. The rest of the question matches the scenario

Comment: @dkozl my bad.  just stressed trying to find a solution. there are no output errors related to this question now

Comment: If there are no binding errors then it should work

Comment: @dkozl precisely! :) I admit this is all new to me. But I have shown the screenshot of my datacontext.  And i have shown my textbox binding.  For some reason the propertychanged event is not being hit.

Comment: @dkozl I believe it is because my property belongs to an object which is in itself a property of my  ApplicationViewModel.BookingWizard.  if i move the property (for instance) *Email* to the BookingWizard class itself it will work